# Using UTF-8 for PHP System call to Python

Tags: php, linux, bash, python-3.x, system

A system call exists in PHP such that

```
system("python3 returnUTF8.py")
```

If I run the Python script on the Linux command line - it works fine, however when I use the PHP system command I get an error "UnicodeEncodingError - can't encode to ascii"...

I understand the problem to be that the print function in Python defaults to the result the caller wants, and this is shown when I run `print (sys.stdout.encoding)`  on the command line I get `UTF-8` and from the system call I get `ANSI_X3.4-1960`.

How can I change the system call in PHP or the Python script to use UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to tell Python what encoding to use; normally this is taken from your terminal locale, but when you use `system()` there is no such locale and then the default `C` locale encoding is used, which is `ANSI_X3.4-1960` (aka ASCII).

Set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING):

```
system("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 returnUTF8.py")
```

or explicitly encode to UTF-8 in your program.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's brought a conclusion to 2 hours of frustration. :)